# iPhone App: show iAds in fullscreen in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, iad

in iPhone/ipad App in ios 4.3 and Higher version supports iads in full-screen for iPad.

By touching on banner view it is showing ads in full screen.

Can we show this ads in full screen programmatically  instead it is displaying full scrren on touching of banner view ?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think not.

The full page is a result of clicking the ad, not the ad itself. The ad is an encouragement, not a product.

Taking the concept of advertising outside of software, this would be similar to a car company forcing you to buy a car instead of just encouraging you to buy a car with its adverts.